# Как при помощи класса Random реализовать случайность открытия той или иной активити?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть метод, который с помощью таймера через некоторое время открывает вторую активность, но так же у меня есть третья активность. Что мне сделать, чтобы с вероятностью 50/50 открывалась вторая либо третья активность?

```
    private fun getAnotherActivity() {
    val intent = Intent(this, ActivityTwo::class.java)

    Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }, 3500)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import kotlin.random.Random

val needOpenTwoActivity = Random.nextBoolean()
val intent = if(needOpenTwoActivity){
    Intent(this, ActivityTwo::class.java)
} else {
    Intent(this, ActivityThree::class.java)
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]